# Automatic Search Using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, file, search-engine, html, www-mechanize

I am trying to write a Perl script which will automatically key in search variables on [this LexisNexis search page](http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/lnacademic/?verb=sr&csi=379740) and retrieve the search results.

I am using the [WWW::Mechanize](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.cpan.org%2Fperldoc%3FWWW%3A%3AMechanize&ei=PcPGVJfxGMW8PZGRgLgM&usg=AFQjCNGOLOItw538wJF1RjwjrCft2iBVfg&sig2=py0LvHwvC_chnwfrrgP24g) module but I am not sure how to figure out the field name of the search bar itself. This is the script I have so far ->

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $m = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $url = "http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/lnacademic/?verb=sr&csi=379740";
$m->get($url);

$m->form_name('f');
$m->field('q', 'Test');
my $response = $m->submit();
print $response->content();
```

However, I think the "Name" of the search box in this website is not "q". I am getting the following Error - "Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at site/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 1442." Any help is much appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: FYI, the [Terms of Service](https://www.lexisnexis.com/terms/general.aspx) for that site say, *"Use of the Online Services via mechanical, programmatic, robotic, scripted or any other automated means is strictly prohibited.  Unless otherwise agreed to by LN in writing, use of the Online Services is permitted only via manually conducted, discrete, individual search and retrieval activities."*

Comment: This is for an academic research project and we have acquired the necessary permissions to conduct this automation. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know. Most people who try to scrape websites don't even bother reading the TOS.

Comment: I'll bet you a nickel that the search page has JavaScript in it to manipulate the page, and Mech doesn't know from JavaScript.  Use the mech-dump utility to see what the forms and fields are on the page, and why they differ from what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! I just realized that the search page has JavaScript. Does any other module support javascprit ?

Comment: @Amritha There are several, such as [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) and [`WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS).

Comment: According to [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=852699) [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/~mattp/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.36/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm) and [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/~lxp/WWW-Scripter-0.030/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod) offer Javascript functionality.

Comment: Be aware that WWW::Selenium uses Selenium RC. To use current Selenium (with WebDriver), use [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver). I wrote a script with it last week and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Amritha: Your problem with JavaScript is the #1 question asked about Mech.  You can see the FAQ here for a list of other modules that handle JavaScript.  http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you disable the JavaScript in your browser then you will notice that the search form doesn't load which means it's being loaded by JavaScript, that's why you are unable to handle it with [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize). Have a look at [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox), this might help you with your task. Check out the [example scripts](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Examples.pm), [cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Cookbook.pod) and [FAQs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/FAQ.pod).

You can also do the same using Selenium, see [Gabor's tutorial on Selenium](http://edumaven.com/test-automation-using-perl/selenium).

Comment: And for using Selenium, [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) is a fine choice, judging by my limited experience.

Comment: Correct, WebDriver is better than RC.

Comment: I write an article for [PerlTricks](http://www.perltricks.com) on [using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://perltricks.com/article/138/2014/12/8/Controlling-Firefox-from-Perl)